# Determine the equation of a line that is perpendicular to the lines r1 and r2 and passes through their point of intersection

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Determine the equation of the line that is perpendicular to the lines $\boldsymbol{r}_1(t)=\langle 4t,1+2t,3t \rangle$ and $\boldsymbol{r}_2(s)=\langle -1+s,-7+2s,-12+3s \rangle$ and passes through their point of intersection.

First, we find the intersection of $\boldsymbol{r}_1(t)$ and $\boldsymbol{r}_2(s)$,
$\left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{3}
    4t &= -1+s \\
    1+2t &= -7+2s \\
    3t &= -12+3s
    \end{alignedat}
    \right. \rightarrow
    \left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{3}
    4t-s &= -1\\
    2t-2s &= -8 \\
    3t-3s &= -12
    \end{alignedat}
    \right. \xrightarrow{R_1-2R_2}
    \left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{3}
    3s &= 15\\
    2t-2s &= -8 \\
    3t-3s &= -12
    \end{alignedat}
    \right. \rightarrow
    \left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{3}
    s &= 5\\
    2t-2(5) &= -8 \\
    3t-3(5) &= -12
    \end{alignedat}
    \right. \rightarrow
    s = 5, t = 1 \\[5pt]$

The two vectors intersect at $(4,3,3)$

The cross product of two non-parallel vectors is a vector that is perpendicular to both of them,
\begin{align*}
\vec{V_1}(4\hat{i}+2\hat{j}+3\hat{k}) \times \vec{V_2}(\hat{i}+2\hat{j}+3\hat{k}) &= 8\hat{j}- 6\hat{k}
\end{align*}

Now here is where I've lost track - not even sure if I am on the right path. I've been trying to figure out this problem for a few hours now and I don't really know where to go. Breaking my brain trying to figure this out

Comment: You're done, you have the vector and the point, so the canonic equation of the line is (if your computations are correct) : $$\frac{x-4}0=\frac{y-3}8=\frac{z-3}{-6}$$ and the parametric form of the equation is $$(0,8,-6)t+(4,3,3),\quad t\in\Bbb R$$ You can visualize it easily.

Comment: thank you, i think I've just been staring at it so long it wasn't making sense anymore.. glad i was on the right track